# Grails - showing page processing/render debug information in development mode

Tags: grails, debugging, rendering

I've been experimenting with Grails for the past two days and, so far, I'm really happy with it.

Coming from Rails, the only thing I've really been missing here is the dev-mode debug information shown after the page has been served.

This is what I mean:

```
Processing UsersController#show (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-06-14 10:28:44) [GET]
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 2) 
Rendering template within layouts/users
Rendering users/show
Completed in 24ms (View: 5, DB: 0) | 200 OK [http://localhost/users/2]
```

Is there any way to get something similar in Grails? I've tried the "debug" plugin but it's not very useful as it only shows the total processing time.

I know it's not hard to roll something of my own (except for that database stats part), I just wanted to make sure I wasn't unnecessarily reinventing the wheel.

Comment: To enable SQL logging (hibernate) put "loggingSql = true" inside the dataSource closure (DataSource.groovy).
Another alternative is using the P6Spy plugin or the Java Melody but neither of them really give you this simple yet very useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's not the answer you are searching for, but you can try tc-Server Developer by SpringSource. There you can see all the Information you are looking for. After changing from Ruby on Rails to Grails, I've searched for the same information. Now I'm happy with the tc-Server solution.

See the video on SpringSource site: http://www.springsource.com/products/tcserver/devedition

This is maybe the reason why SpringSource doesn't include the Ruby on Rails style output to the console. I would still like to turn this output on, but I can live without too.